# merge 2 dataframes in pandas and with condition

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two `DataFrame`

```
df1; columns - a, b, c
df2; columns - d, e
```

I want to `merge` df1 left join with df2 on `df1.a = df2.d` and a new column 'f' on the result with `pd.isnull(e,c)`

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you add sample of data in `df1`, `df2` (3,4 rows) and desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
merged = df1.merge(df2, left_on='a', right_on='d' how='left')
merged['f'] = pd.isnull(merged[['e', 'c']]).any(axis=1)
```

See `.merge()` [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Use `.any(axis=1)` or `.all(axis=1)` depending on what you want do check for.

Comment: Thanks Jansen. How can I join dataframes with '<>' condition.
join on df1.a <> df2.d

Comment: Sounds like you might want `merge(.., how='outer')` and then `merged[merged.a != merged.d]`

Comment: I'm not sure what you said do the needful, to be specific my equivalent sql is "select * from df1 inner join df2 on df1.b=df2.e and df1.b <> df2.d and df1.c = 0"

Comment: Would you mind asking a new question, I'll provide a more detailed answer there.